# Jhipster using custom entity-client sub-generator

Tags: jhipster

I am trying to create a blueprint for entity-client sub-generator by following the [official guide](https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-blueprint/). Tried several times. But when I try to use the generated blueprint, while importing jdl, it always says

*Trying to use blueprint generator-jhipster-helloworld

**WARNING!** No blueprint found for entity-client falling back to default generator*

[image]

then it generates the entity clients in the default way.

I can see the blueprint is linked into the node-modules folder of the generated app. 
[image: Blueprint is linked in node_modules]

If anybody has created a simple working "entity-client sub-generator" blueprint, Please share the code with me. For example, "that adds `<h1>lorem ipsum<h1>` on the top of component.html file for the generated client of entity (on importing a simple jdl with just one entity)" would be sufficient.

*Sample JDL*

```
entity Item{
    code String required,
    description String required,
    quantity Integer required 
}
```

Best Regards.